# Get a modal carousel to open on the image that has been selected

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the carousel that's within a modal to open up on the image that has been selected by the user. I've tried `data-slide-to="##"` but no look with that. I'll post the code below. I'll remove repeated code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Name LTD - Gallery</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-secondary fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Name</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
<header class="bg-primary py-5 mb-5">
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1 class="display-4 text-white mt-5 mb-2">Gallery</h1>
          <p class="lead mb-5 text-white-50">Below Is A Portfolio Of Just A Few Of The Jobs We Have Done So Far </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
      <!-- Page Content -->
      <div class="container">

          <h1 class="font-weight-light text-center text-lg-left mt-4 mb-0">Click An Image To Enter Slideshow</h1>

          <hr class="mt-2 mb-5">

          <div class="row text-center text-lg-left">

              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                  <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".imgGal" data-slide-to="0">
                      <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="img/img14.png" alt="">
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                  <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".imgGal" data-slide-to="1">
                      <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="img/img15.png" alt="">
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                  <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".imgGal" data-slide-to="2">
                      <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="img/img9.png" alt="">
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                  <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".imgGal" data-slide-to="3">
                      <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="img/img10.png" alt="">
                  </a>
              </div>

          </div>

      </div>

  <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="modal fade imgGal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                          <div class="item active">
                              <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img14.png" alt="..." style="width: 100%">
                          </div>
                          <div class="item">
                              <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img15.png" alt="..." style="width: 100%">
                          </div>
                          <div class="item">
                              <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img9.png" alt="..." style="width: 100%">
                          </div>
                          <div class="item">
                              <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img10.png" alt="..." style="width: 100%">
                          </div>

                      </div>

                      <!-- Controls -->
                      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- /.container -->


  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Name 2020</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </footer>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

So currently when the user selects image 1, image 1 is shown on the carousel but then if image 2 is selected image 1 still shows first etc. So what I want is for the user to be able to select say image 3, and image 3 be selected on the carousel so they don't have to scroll through the carousel to get to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should point your images to the slider also by doing **data-target="#carousel-example-generic"** where as you are pointing the  tag to only modal so that is the reason it is not updating the slider,

So may be the following code helps you

```html
<div class="row text-center text-lg-left">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
    <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".imgGal">
    <img src="img/img14.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
    <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".imgGal">
    <img src="img/img15.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
    <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".imgGal">
    <img src="img/img9.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
    <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".imgGal">
    <img src="img/img10.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```